# Building Autoencoder with Softmax classifier - Input mismatch error

Tags: pytorch, classification, autoencoder

I am trying to train an auto-encoder with a softmax classifier to replicate the results in this paper [Intriguing properties of neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6199).

My implementation is the following:

```
n_embedded = 400
class AE400_10(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AE400_10, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28*28, n_embedded), nn.Sigmoid())
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_embedded, 28*28))
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28*28, 10))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28*28)
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        out = self.classifier(decoded) ##NEW UPDATED
                        
        return decoded, F.log_softmax(out)
```

For the training I have the following:

```
model = AE400_10().to(device)

criterion1 = nn.MSELoss()
criterion2 = nn.BCELoss()
            
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
for epoch in range(epochs): 
    total_batch = len(train_set) // batch_size_train
    
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(MNSIT_train): 
        X = data.to(device)
        Y = target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        decoded, out = model(X)
       
        loss1 = criterion1(decoded, inputs) 
        loss2 = criterion2(out, labels)
        loss = loss1 + loss2
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if (batch_idx+1) % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch [%d/%d], lter [%d/%d], Loss: %.4f'%(epoch+1, epochs, batch_idx+1, total_batch, cost.item()))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [128 x 400], m2: [784 x 10] at
> /Users/soumith/mc3build/conda-bld/pytorch_1549593514549/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:940

I understand this is an error in the dimension but I am not sure why it is happening.

**::UPDATE::**
I fixed the input to the classifier based on the comments below and now I am getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (784) must match the size of tensor
> b (28) at non-singleton dimension 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `nn.Sequential` so I'm not sure why exactly this happens but if you
replace

```
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28*28, 10))
```

with

```
self.classifier = nn.Linear(28*28, 10)
```

your code works

-->

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
n_embedded = 400
class AE400_10(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AE400_10, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28*28, n_embedded), nn.Sigmoid())
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_embedded, 28*28))
        self.test = nn.Linear(28*28, 10)
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28*28, 10))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1,28*28)
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        out = self.classifier(decoded)
        return decoded, F.log_softmax(out)
      
x = torch.ones(128,28,28)
model = AE400_10()
model(x)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but I got the following error when I tried to start training: RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (784) must match the size of tensor b (28) at non-singleton dimension 3

Answer (score 0):

instead of `encoded`   out = self.classifier(encoded)
put  decoded as input of classifier

```
  out = self.classifier(decoded)
```

I think, here is why you are getting the mismatch, because the classifier is expecting a tensor of 28 *28 as input as defined in your code.

Then,when calling  the criterions:

```
 loss1 = criterion1(decoded, X) 
 loss2 = criterion2(out, Y)
```

Comment: I have updated the code and now I am getting a new error, pasted above

Comment: Hello @Wanderer, I think the error is the way you have called the two criterions.  I have updated my answer above.